# Flat files within a zipfile in Python

Tags: python

I am doing:

```
z = zipfile.ZipFile('myzip.zip', 'w')
z.write('/some/path/mytxt1.txt')
z.write('/some/other/path/mytxt2.txt')
z.close()
```

This is preserving the file paths within the zip. I just want my desired files to sit flat in the zip file. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`ZipFile.write()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile#zipfile.ZipFile.write) takes the second argument, `arcname`. Just set it to [`os.path.basename()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) of the first argument to remove the path:

```
def zip_write(zip, filename):
    zip.write(filename, os.path.basename(filename))

z = zipfile.ZipFile('myzip.zip', 'w')
zip_write(z, '/some/path/mytxt1.txt')
zip_write(z, '/some/other/path/mytxt2.txt')
z.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response!